# C# Databinding SelectedIndexChanged call

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, combobox

I am using a SelectedIndexChanged function for a combobox to update the content of my DataGridview item. I have the combobox data bound to keep track of it's currently selected record. However, when I changed the combobox index it updates the datagridview as if the selected value was the same. This means once I have selected a different index value in the combobox, I have to select it again to run the function with the proper value.

Am I missing something here? Do I need to call the check for the current datarow selected in the combobox before calling the SelectedIndexChanged function?

Comment: Maybe add a little code here?  And do you _call_ the eventhandler?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the page life cycle issue, as the datagrid will be fired before the slected index change if its in the page load event. at which point the index wont have changed so the data will be the same.